# How can I set the screen refresh rate for a CRT VGA monitor in Leopard?

Tags: screen, leopard, refresh

I need to operate a CRT monitor in 100 Hz (1280 x 1024) on a Leopard Machine.
The same monitor was working fine on a Tiger machine in the mentioned range but I switched to Leopard and it does not show the 100 Hz option in the list any more (but I am sure the monitor can support it). 
Is there a way to manually modify the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it seems that there is no way to do this. I ended up changing my Graphics card to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This handy utility [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/functions/page17/page17.html) can give you the option to adjust your monitor settings.

There is also this [utility](http://www.3dexpress.de/) (which I haven't tried/tested)

Comment: thanks. But is there a system call or command line utility or some API to do this. I tried both the utilities you mentioned already and they don't work for me (I can't get to 100 Hz in 1280 x 1024 and I am sure my Monitor supports it).